# Logistic Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My data is split as train and test from a dataset df.
Can I split the train and test as X_train, Y_train from train and X_test, Y_test from test?

Sample code:-

```
train, test = train_test_split(df, train_size=0.8, stratify=df.y_yes.values, random_state=5)

#Can I do the below splitting?
X_train, Y_train = train_test_split(train, random_state=5)
X_test, Y_test = train_test_split(test, random_state=5)
```

[train.head and test.head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXK43.png)

Comment: Well train amd test already consists of the x's and y's. Just filter train and test with the variable names of y and rest and there you go. And also - your question has nothing to do with logistic regression, yoj may want to edit your title.

Comment: I have no idea why I got downvotes on my question. I am unable to figure out how to take the train and test and predict my outcome and calculate the AUC.

Comment: Thanks, @FatihAkici, I will try this.

Comment: The reason may be because it is too straightforward (answer can be found in any tutorial) or is not reproducible or shows no effort. Please share train.head() and test.head() inside your post so people can help you better.

Comment: "*I am unable to figure out how to [...]*" - yes, but you don't ask *that*... The answer to you "*can I?*" question is simply **yes** (now, whether this would be meaningful, is another discussion)

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find a solution to this, so used the regular splitting expression:-

```
 X = df_clean[['previous', 'emp.var.rate', 'euribor3m', 'nr.employed', 
'pdays_missing', 'poutcome_success' , 'poutcome_nonexistent','pdays_bet_5_15']]
 y = df_clean['y_yes']
 X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, 
 random_state=5)
 print(X_train.shape)
 print(X_test.shape)
 print(Y_train.shape)
 print(Y_test.shape)
```